# Error response body format from a request with specific "Accept" header

Tags: rest, http, httpresponse

My HTTP/Rest API has a resource endpoint that can handle "application/json" and "text/csv" response body formats which are specified via the "Accept" header on the request.

In case of error, like an HTTP 400, 500 response etc., i wonder what response body format should be used for returning error information. If used with `application/json`, it pretty obvious the error information must be in JSON format. But what format to use in case of `text/csv`, or any other more "exotic" mime types ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a right / wrong answer here, but I think error message bodies should be in one type regardless of the request (i.e. `application/json`). This is to simplify error handling by the consumer. Depending on your service, your consumer might use CSV for one request, XML for another, as well as JSON. On their end, when errors do occur, dealing with a consistent error response would be ideal.

Comment: @MoA I wondered if there were some kind of "best practice" about this subject. It seems the best solution for me too.

Comment: Just had a look around, and found the UK Land Registry API (fairly mature API) which can respond in CSV, XML, JSON, etc. They're returning errors based on the format, rather than setting to one type across all (i.e. the opposite of what I suggested). Have a play around `GET http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/data/ppi/address.json?town=LONDON` . You can change the `.json`to `.csv` or `.xml`. I know its not exactly on the headers as you specified, but the outcome might be relevant. Maybe setting the error response in-line with type is the right approach.

Comment: Seems this API returns "text/javascript" content type on error, whatever file extension (which is another format detection method). At least with this kind of error: `GET http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/data/ppi/address.json?ggre=gregr`. This request with wrong query string returns an HTTP 500 in "text/javascript" format, with HTML in response body .

Comment: That's right. Another source of inspiration is Oracles API which returns JSON or XML - `https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/messaging-cloud/csmes/using-rest-api.html#GUID-5EA9CC73-0639-4560-8699-706D5A96FB03` (error response).

Comment: So, according to the oracle API, it seems the good answer is to return an HTTP 406 if the Accept Mime Type is any of "application/json" or "application/xml" where in the later cases the error messages can be translated to theses formats. That's the default behavior of my Spring Framework environment in which i develop this API (i was now struggling to change this behavior, but this is another concern). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP server is free to disregard the `Accept` header if none of the formats are available.

Given that there's not really a 'standard' CSV error response, I would default to `application/problem+json`, `text/html` or maybe even `text/plain`.

Comment: Seems the best solution ihmo. As stated by user "Mo A" in the comments of original question, having error responses in the same format for the whole API whatever the Accept request and content-type response is easier for clients to deal with.

Comment: @sgt-hartman I would not universally agree with that. We use text/html errors or application/problem+json errors depending on the accept header. The browser gets a pretty error response and api clients get a parseable one =)